# EF Core 5 dropping HiLo sequence

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I've recently migrate one of my asp net core projects to .net5. In my project I've used EF, after migration I upgraded to EF core 5. I'm using HiLo for my PKs and just yesterday I added a new column and when generated a migration I've noticed that EF dropped all my sequences related to HiLo PK.

Is this a new behavior on EF Core 5? Is this a bug? Should I do something to prevent this from happening?

EDIT

This is one of the generated migrations, drops are commented:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "centers_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "dock_call_message_templates_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "dock_call_notifications_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "dock_calls_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "dock_state_logs_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "dock_waiting_queue_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "docks_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "factory_call_message_templates_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "factory_call_notifications_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "factory_calls_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        //migrationBuilder.DropSequence(
        //    name: "trucks_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
            name: "registry_complete",
            schema: "dbo",
            table: "trucks",
            type: "bit",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: false);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTimeOffset>(
            name: "registry_completion_date",
            schema: "dbo",
            table: "trucks",
            type: "datetimeoffset",
            nullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "registry_complete",
            schema: "dbo",
            table: "trucks");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "registry_completion_date",
            schema: "dbo",
            table: "trucks");

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "centers_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "dock_call_message_templates_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "dock_call_notifications_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "dock_calls_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "dock_state_logs_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "dock_waiting_queue_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "docks_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "factory_call_message_templates_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "factory_call_notifications_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "factory_calls_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);

        //migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
        //    name: "trucks_hilo",
        //    schema: "dbo",
        //    incrementBy: 10);
    }
```

This is my entity configuration:

```
public class TruckConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Truck>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Truck> builder)
    {

        builder.ConfigBaseEntity<Truck, int>("trucks");

        builder.Property(t => t.LicensePlate)
               .HasColumnName("license_plate")
               .HasMaxLength(MAX_LICENSEPLATE_LENGTH)
               .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(t => t.LogisticOperator)
               .HasColumnName("logistic_operator")
               .HasMaxLength(MAX_LOGISTIC_OPERATOR_LENGTH)
               .IsRequired(false);

        builder.Property(t => t.RegistryComplete)
               .HasColumnName("registry_complete")
               .IsRequired(true)
               .HasDefaultValue(false);

        builder.Property(t => t.RegistryCompletionDate)
               .HasColumnName("registry_completion_date")
               .IsRequired(false);

        builder.HasOne(t=>(DockWaitingQueueItem)t.DockWaitingQueue)
               .WithOne(i => (Truck)i.Truck)
               .IsRequired(true)
               .HasForeignKey<DockWaitingQueueItem>(i => i.TruckId)
               .HasConstraintName("FK_dock_waiting_queue_truck")
               .HasPrincipalKey<Truck>(t => t.Id)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
               
        builder.OwnsOne(t => (Driver)t.Driver,
                        d =>
                        {
                            d.ToTable("truck_drivers");
                            d.Property(d => d.Name)
                             .HasColumnName("driver_name")
                             .IsRequired()
                             .HasMaxLength(MAX_DRIVER_NAME_LENGTH);

                            d.Property(d => d.Surnames)
                             .HasColumnName("driver_surnames")
                             .IsRequired()
                             .HasMaxLength(MAX_DRIVER_SURNAMES_LENGTH);

                            d.Property(d => d.Language)
                             .HasColumnName("driver_language")
                             .IsRequired()
                             .HasMaxLength(MAX_DRIVER_LANGUAGE_LENGTH);

                            d.Property(d => d.PhoneNumber)
                             .HasColumnName("driver_phone_number")
                             .IsRequired()
                             .HasMaxLength(MAX_DRIVER_PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH);
                        });

        builder.HasMany(t => (IEnumerable<FactoryCall>)t.FactoryCalls)
               .WithOne(fc => (Truck)fc.Truck)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasForeignKey(fc => fc.TruckId)
               .HasConstraintName("FK_factory_calls_trucks")
               .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.HasMany(t => (IEnumerable<DockCall>)t.DockCalls)
               .WithOne(dc => (Truck)dc.Truck)
               .IsRequired()
               .HasConstraintName("FK_dock_calls_trucks")
               .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.HasIndex(t => t.LicensePlate)
               .HasDatabaseName("IX_trucks_license_plate")
               .IsClustered(false);
               
        
    }
}
```

And, finally, this is code for "ConfigBaseEntity"

```
public static EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> ConfigBaseEntity<TEntity, TKey>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder, string tableName) where TEntity: BaseObject<TKey>
    {
        builder.ToTable(tableName)
               .HasKey(ent => ent.Id)
               .IsClustered()
               .HasName($"PK_{tableName}");

        builder.Property(ent => ent.Id)
               .UseHiLo($"{tableName}_hilo", MAIN_DB_SCHEMA)
               .HasColumnName("id")
               .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(t => t.CreationDate)
               .HasColumnName("creation_date")
               .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(t => t.ArchivedDate)
               .HasColumnName("archived_date")
               .IsRequired(false);

        builder.Ignore(t => t.IsArchived);

        return builder;
    }
```

Not sure if this is enough for you people to have an idea of what I'm talking about.
As you can see, EF added the two columns but, at the same time generated code to drop all HiLo sequences. The rest of my configurations looks very similar to the one I've posted here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Post your code and your migration. What did the SQL code look like? [UseHiLo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverpropertybuilderextensions.usehilo?view=efcore-5.0) hasn't gone away.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Posted code, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Facing same error but in EF Core v6.0.8 and the issue is because of
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("custom db schema"); in db context OnModelCreating method.
Without explicit configuration of custom schema, everything works fine.

That's a bug and is already been reported on GitHub. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28223